# Como criar uma virtualenv com uma vesão do python diferente das instaladas?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Eu estou usando a virtualenv para instalar alguns pacotes dos meus projetos para que os mesmos não entrem em conflito, mas estou precisando usar uma versão do python que não esta instalada no sistema, como uso linux o mesmo já vem com a 2.7 e a 3.5 instalada, mas eu preciso usar a 3.4.0, mas não queria instalar uma nova versão do python no sistema, como eu poderia criar uma virtualenv com uma versão de python especifica ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma olhada no projeto [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) com ele você consegue instalar fácilmente várias versões diferentes de python sem afetar as versões já instaladas no S.O.

Depois de instalar o pyenv, basta vc instalar a versão de python que você quer (e.g.):

```
$ pyenv install 3.4.2
```

Com a versão do python instalada, basta você criar o `virtualenv` apontando para a versão do python desejada (e.g.)

```
$ virtualenv -p ~/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/bin/python venv
```

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo instalar o  pyenv, teria como instalar ele pelo pip ?

Comment: @Arcashaid da uma olhada no https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer la tem as instruções de como instalar

Answer (score 0):

Se o teu ambiente for anaconda:

> conda create --name meu_amb_py34 python=3.4

Detalhes em http://brito.blog.incolume.com.br/2018/06/anaconda.html